# Como mudar valor de uma variável apenas quando radio buton estiver checked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

No arquivo `.php` há uma certa variável.

```
  <?php
    $freteselecionado = "<script>document.write(checado)</script>";
```

Então tenho dois `input` do tipo `radio` para receber o valor.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio_01" name="tipo_frete" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="radio_02" name="tipo_frete" value="2">
```

Minha função utilizando *jQuery*, mas algo está saindo errado.

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            let checado = false;
            $( "#radio_01" ).change(function() {
            var $input = $( this );
            if ($input.is( ":checked" )) {
                checado = true;
            }}).change();

            $( "#radio_02" ).change(function() {
            var $input = $( this );
            if ($input.is( ":checked" )) {
                checado = true;
            }}).change();
        });
</script>
```

Como fazer para alterar o valor da variável php apenas quando for realmente `checked`? O que acontece é que quando é carregado o *DOM* o valor já está `TRUE`.

Comment: Para fazer isso, você vai ter que enviar o  valor utilizando ajax

Comment: Qual é o objetivo do seu código?

Comment: @WictorChaves como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: estou querendo liberar um botão na aplicação apenas se o usuário selecionar determinado  tipo de frete.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso utilizando apenas o javascript :)

Comment: como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88549/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-andre-martins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como conversado via chat, esta o código ao qual resolve o seu problema.

Basta colocar "checked" em um dos input radio, assim sempre estará selecionando um dos frente, desta forma não há a necessidade de ocultar ou mostrar o botão, já que o frente vai esta sempre selecionado de alguma forma.

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio_opcao" name="tipo_frete" value="1" checked> PAC
<input type="radio" class="radio_opcao" name="tipo_frete" value="2"> Sedex

<input id="btn_frete" type="button" value="Pagamento">
```